# GTK+ within Python 2 and 3

Tags: installation, application-development

Can GTK+ with Python create app on Ubuntu OS?

Comment: Please further specify the issues you have, or what your project will be. In the present form there is not much more to say than *"yes, they can"*.

Comment: This has a good answer with an upvote, and the question, while general, is both clear and constructive. I see no reason to close this.

Comment: @EliahKagan - the close votes were before the edit.  See the original question

Comment: I agree with Eliah Kagan. I had just opened the subject then few hours later, some users closed this case for no reason. I want to see if any user who likes to throw to discuss as brainstorm about this the subject. Cuz I am a new member as a rookie.

Comment: Maybe I will think about set a group of beginners for learning, discussing, and helping like these. if anyone who wants to join this, then say join me by add comment if there are enough many..      Only GTK+ within Python 3.3.0!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes of course, you can develop applications both in Python 2 and Python 3 with PyGtk.

Check [here how to use PyGtk for Python 3](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) or [here for Python 2](http://www.pygtk.org/)

Also you can use [Quickly](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly) ([video](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/)) which will generate much of the boilerplate code **and** make your project easier to release.

Comment: Thank you for  answering my question. I am a new member as rookie. Lol! I do not understand why some users closed the case of my subject in few hours. Anyway, Why doesn't GTK+ support 64 bits? Oh, I was like darn.

Comment: Although PyGTK supports many 64 bit operating systems, even if being 32 bit in some, it does not mean that you cannot use it; it just wont be the 64 bit release.

Comment: Also consider pygobject, as pyGTK is depreciated

Comment: The provided link for Python 3 is for GTK+3 which uses PyGObject.